# simple feature - create new points with certain properties

Tags: r, gps, gis, r-sf

I've a `simple features` with a simple point, arround this point I like to create 6 **new** points **equal distributed and 100 meter away** from the orginal point. Is this easily  solvable in R (sf) and do you have perhaps an example how I could implement something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by buffering the point by 100 meters, cast it to a linestring, and then sample the buffered linestring:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(tidyverse)


set.seed(41)
point <- st_sfc(st_point(c(0, 51.5))) %>% st_set_crs(4326) # a point around London

buffer <- st_buffer(point, dist = 100) %>% 
  st_cast('LINESTRING')

six_points <- st_sample(buffer, size = 6, type = 'regular')
#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_sample assumes that they are
#> planar

#distances:
six_points %>% st_as_sf() %>% st_cast('POINT') %>% st_distance(point)
#> Units: [m]
#>          [,1]
#> [1,] 100.5366
#> [2,] 100.2739
#> [3,] 100.7187
#> [4,] 100.5599
#> [5,] 100.2410
#> [6,] 100.6761
```

Pretty close. Choosing a better crs would help if you need cm accuracy.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = point, col = 'red') + 
  geom_sf(data = buffer) +
  geom_sf(data = six_points, color = 'turquoise', size = 4) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

On a map:

```
library(mapview)
mapview(point) +
  buffer +
  six_points
```

[image: library(mapview) mapview(point) + buffer + six_points]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>